# Flutter AbsorbPointer vs IgnorePointer difference

Tags: dart, flutter

What is the difference between `AbsorbPointer` and `IgnorePointer` in flutter?

Docs mention:

> AbsorbPointer prevents its subtree from receiving pointer events by terminating hit testing at itself.
>
> IgnorePointer, which also prevents its children from receiving pointer events but is itself invisible to hit testing.

I didn't get what is the real life difference between the two.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600747/flutter-ignore-touch-events-on-a-widget

Comment: @Novo I believe that doesn't tell the difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter: Ignore touch events on a Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600747/flutter-ignore-touch-events-on-a-widget)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The difference is when we have two widgets overlapping each other, that can both receive clicks.

Consider a red and blue square, both clickable, where the blue square is smaller and on the top of the red square:

```dart
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
     Container(color: Colors.red),
     Container(width: 42, height: 42, color: Colors.blue),
  ],
)
```

By default, without `IgnorePointer`/`AbsorbPointer`, tapping the blue square will send a click event on blue and red gets nothing.

In that situation, wrapping blue square into an `AbsorbPointer` means that when tapping the blue square, neither the blue square nor the red one gets the click event.

If we instead used an `IgnorePointer`, the red square would receive click events when tapping the blue square.

Comment: Interesting, but has anyone needed this distinction?

Comment: Interesting. Could you replace the documentation for these widgets with this short answer?

Comment: Actually in real life when you will come across some problems like, if you don't want the gestures in the maps or don't want any two-finger zoom or else, then you will need this.

Comment: It is really interesting but when I try to disable my click events on WebView using webview_flutter none of them works. Is anyone know why?

Comment: tks bro, my brain just rescued!!!