# How can I disable the gestures in mapbox in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, android-mapview, fluttermap

Can I **disable** the gestures present in Mapbox in flutter *such as zoom, moving through two-finger*, etc? If yes, then please tell me. I have researched but found nowhere. If anyone of you know then **please tel**l.

Comment: You could use absorbpointer or ignore pointer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65HoWqBboI8 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qV9pqHWxYgI and check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430842/flutter-absorbpointer-vs-ignorepointer-difference

Comment: Good luck in your flutter project :)

Answer (score 0):

With `flutter-mapbox-gl` you may disable these when creating new `MapboxMap` widget by passing the following parameters.

```dart
MapboxMap(
                  scrollGesturesEnabled: false,
                  rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
                  tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: false,
...)
```