# How to disable Dropdownlist once user has selected an item in the Dropdownlist in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My DropdownMenuItem coming from API. How to disable the dropDown once user select a item from the list?

```
child: DropdownButton<Partner>(
                          value:
                              _selectedLab, //USER SELECTED DROPDOWN ITEM VALUE
                          hint: Text("Select Lab"),
                          isExpanded: true,
                          items: data.map((Partner data) =>
                                  DropdownMenuItem<Partner>(
                                    child: Text("${data.partnerName}"),
                                    value: data,
                                  )).toList().cast<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>(),
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedLab = val!;
                              encLabId = val.encPartnerId;
                              getTestByLabResult = getTestByLab();
                            });
                          },
                        ),
```

Comment: you can use `AbsorbPointer` based on selected bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bool on state `bool absoreTap = false;` and wrap you `DropdownButton`  with `AbsorbPointer` like

```dart
      AbsorbPointer(
              absorbing: absoreTap,
              child: DropdownButton<Partner>(
                          value:
                              _selectedLab, //USER SELECTED DROPDOWN ITEM VALUE
                          hint: Text("Select Lab"),
                          isExpanded: true,
                          items: data.map((Partner data) =>
                                  DropdownMenuItem<Partner>(
                                    child: Text("${data.partnerName}"),
                                    value: data,
                                  )).toList().cast<DropdownMenuItem<Partner>>(),
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              _selectedLab = val!;
                              encLabId = val.encPartnerId;
                              getTestByLabResult = getTestByLab();
                             absoreTap = true; /// 
                            });
                          },
                        ),
```

You can also check Ignore-pointer here is the [different between them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55430842/10157127)

Comment: Its Working like charm.. Thanks for your Time!