# How do I prevent when I touch screen, scrolling stops in Flutter

Tags: flutter, scroll, touchscreen

I use globalkey and Scrollable.ensurevisible for each titles. It works well, but when l touch screen after click title, scrolling stops.
Do u have any idea?

```
///  Scroll to the selected category
await Scrollable.ensureVisible(
  widget.categoriesList[index].key.currentContext!,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  alignment: 0.05,
  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
);
```

Comment: Do you mean that it's stopping before the scroll-to-visible code is done?

Comment: If I touch screen, scrolling to globalkey stops.

Comment: Okay, try rendering something 'on top' of the screen, an invisible gesture detector that no-ops, or the absorb pointer option from this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220859/flutter-disable-touch-on-the-entire-screen
You'll want to have a state for if it should block or not, and set it to 'true' just before the await you have, and false again after when you're done scrolling